# Entity Framework 4.0 function import returns a different result to running stored procedure directly

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure which calculates forecast sales figures for a given date period.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateMonthlyForecast]
    @CustomerID Int = -1,
    @ProductID Int = -1,
    @ForecastDate DateTime = NULL,
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @FinishDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Calculates each month's forecast as an individual row
    SELECT  [Year], [MonthNumber], [BaseSales], [ForecastSales]
    FROM    dbo.GetMonthlyForecast(@CustomerID, @ProductID, @StartDate, @FinishDate,     @ForecastDate)
END
```

That runs fine and produces the values I would expect. I have created a function import in the Entity Framework designer that should pull in these results as a collection of a complex type  MonthlyForecastResult. The problem I am having is that the values in the MonthlyForecastResult object aren't the same values generated by the stored procedure.

Looking at a trace in the SQL Server Profiler I can see the EXEC call generated by entity framework when the function is called. Executing the stored procedure (using the generated call) directly in SQL Server returns the correct result but the MonthlyForecastResult objects returned by the function don't have the same values as the stored procedure results.

Additionally the BaseSales and ForecastSales values are always the same value in the MonthlyForecastResult objects even if they are very different in the stored procedure's results.

The only thing I could think of that might be causing it would be some mix up with entity keys, but the problem happens even if only 1 row would be return and I wouldn't have thought that entity keys would come into play on Complex Type objects anyway.

**UPDATE**

I discovered today after updating the production version of the application that the behaviour I'm having trouble with only seems to occur in the development environment. Running the application on the client's server connected to their database seems to be producing the correct figures (in that there are the differences I would expect between the base sales and forecast sales). This seems strange though because I updated their database using the exact definitions from the development database and updated the application by reinstalling it using a clean setup, so it should be the same as well.

**EXAMPLE**

If I ask it to calculate the monthly forecast for September 2012 the execute call generated by EF shows up in SQL Server Profiler as:

```
exec [dbo].[CalculateMonthlyForecast] @CustomerID=1,@ProductID=2,@ForecastDate=NULL,@StartDate='2012-09-01',@FinishDate='2012-10-01'
```

If I copy that and run it in SQL Server I get back three rows:

```
Year  Month  BaseSales  ForecastSales
2012   8       660         660
2012   9       3590        10890
2012   10      1652        1652
```

Note: The extra months are because it is calculated based on weeks and the start of the first week and the end of the last week in September overlap other months.

This is correct according to my manual calculations but the MonthlyForecastResult objects don't have those values. The three objects generated have these values instead:

```
Year  Month  BaseSales  ForecastSales
2012   8       498         498
2012   9       9970        9970
2012   10      2717        2717
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the stored procedure results to be different from the Complex Type values?

Comment: Are you sure that you are really returning complex type and not entity type? Show how some example of data difference.

Comment: It's definitely returning a complex type. I created MonthlyForecastResult using the 'Create a New Complex Type' command when I created the function import for the stored procedure and the class shows up in the Complex Types folder in the data model designer in Visual Studio.

Comment: Run SQL Server Profiler and get the SQL that EF is sending to the database when this sproc is called. Maybe the data isn't getting sent, or isn't getting sent correctly.

Comment: @Gromer - I'm not sure I quite understand. The execute call in the example was taken directly from SQL Server Profiler when Entity framework called the stored procedure, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ugh, I totally misread that part, ignore my comment.  That is weird!  I've been using sprocs with EF a lot lately and haven't had these issues.